# react-native-paper Modal not hiding all others elements when visible

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-paper

My modal does not go completely above all the other components under Android but works well under Ios.

I tried to change hierarchy of my components, play with zIndex and absolute position but my green button is always visible but not touchable when modal show up.

**Modal not visible (Android & Ios):**

[image: Modal not visible (Android & Ios)]

**Modal visible (Android) *button is still visible*:**

[image: Modal visible (Android)]

**Modal visible (Ios) *button is NOT visible*:**

[image: Modal visible (Ios)]

My component:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Spinner
    visible={spinner}
    textContent={'Recherche de jardins...'}
    textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
  />
  <View style={[styles.noThreadContainer, {flex: 5}]}>
    <View style={styles.noThreadView}>
      <Title style={styles.noThreadTitle}>
        Personne autour de vous à {toKm(finalDistance)} km
      </Title>
      <Button icon="map-marker-distance" mode="contained" onPress={showModal}>
        Modifier la distance
      </Button>
    </View>
  </View>
  <SliderModal style={{flex: 1}} />
</View>;
```

SliderModal:

```js
const SliderModal = () => {
  const minValue = 5000;
  const maxValue = 200000;
  const [kmValue, setKmValue] = useState(finalDistance || 5000);
  return (
    <Provider>
      <Portal>
        <Modal
          visible={visible}
          dismissable={false}
          onDismiss={hideModal}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.sliderContainer}>
          <Title style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginBottom: 40}}>
            Modifier la distance
          </Title>
          <View style={styles.kmContainer}>
            <Text>{toKm(minValue)} km</Text>
            <Title>{toKm(kmValue)} km</Title>
            <Text>{toKm(maxValue)} km</Text>
          </View>
          <Slider
            onValueChange={setKmValue}
            value={finalDistance}
            step={5000}
            style={styles.slider}
            minimumValue={minValue}
            maximumValue={maxValue}
            minimumTrackTintColor="brown"
            maximumTrackTintColor="#77DD77"
          />
          <View style={[styles.kmContainer, styles.buttonContainer]}>
            <Button color="brown" onPress={hideModal}>
              Fermer
            </Button>
            <Button
              labelStyle={{color: 'white'}}
              color="#77DD77"
              mode="contained"
              onPress={() => {
                hideModal();
                setFinalDistance(kmValue);
              }}>
              Valider
            </Button>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </Portal>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

StyleSheet:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    sliderContainer: {backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 20},
    slider: {width: '100%', height: 40},
    kmContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    buttonContainer: {
      marginTop: 30,
    },
    noThreadView: {
      alignSelf: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      width: width * 0.8,
    },
    noThreadContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      alignContent: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    noThreadTitle: {
      marginBottom: 15,
      alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    spinnerTextStyle: {
      color: '#FFF',
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before button add !visible, like this:

```
 { !visible && <Button icon="map-marker-distance" mode="contained" onPress={showModal}>
                  Modifier la distance
                </Button>
 }
```

Comment: Yep easy! I don't even know why I didn't think of this sooner... 

Answer (score -1):

Use react-native-modal Modal instead of react-native-paper Modal. The problem will gone after.

```
> npm i react-native-modal

import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
```

Close the server and re-run commmand

```
> npm run android
```

Or

```
> npx react-native run-android
```

Comment: The OP clearly wants to use react-native-paper's modal because that's the design system they are using. Telling them to just replace the modal with the standard one isn't very helpful unless you also intend to show them how to skin it to match the one used in react-native-paper.